# I am getting many errors while trying to install the Commontator Rails gem.`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, comments

I have been trying to install the Rails gem Commentator all day on an art project I am working on.  The instructions seem simple enough, but nothing has been working right, even as I followed the instructions.  Currently, after I click on this link I put onto my art show page:

```
<%= commontator_thread(@art) %>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `art_url' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x00007ffde6ecd588>
```

I put the commontator thread in my art show page.  Here is my arts controller:

```
class ArtsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @arts = Art.all
  end


  def new
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @art = Art.new
  end

  def create
    @art = Art.new(art_params)
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @art.artist = @artist
    if @art.save
      redirect_to @art.artist
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @artist = Artist.find(params[:artist_id])
    @art = Art.find(params[:id])
    commontator_thread_show(@art)
  end

  def update
    @art = Art.find(params[:id])
    if @art.update(art_params)
      redirect_to @art
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @art = Art.find(params[:id])
    @art.destroy
    redirect_to arts
  end

  def edit
    @art = Art.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def art_params
    params.require(:art).permit(:title, :description, :completion_date, :inspiration, :available, :price_cents, :tags_as_string, :tag_list)
  end
end
```

This is what shows up in my errors page on my browser while I am on local host:

```
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb

              @helpers.#{method}(*args)
            end
          RUBY
          public_send(method, *args)
        else
          super
        end
      end
      # Keeps the part of the script name provided by the global
      # context via ENV["SCRIPT_NAME"], which `mount` doesn't know
```

I was getting many other errors earlier today, speaking about the comment controller not having a create method or show method, but the gem instructions did not specify anything about creating a comment controller at all, so I am very lost.  I am new to programming, so any help would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: please provide the link to the actual gem documentation you're referring to

Comment: Sure, here you go:
https://github.com/lml/commontator

Comment: See instructions, looks like you're missing a line from your model https://github.com/lml/commontator#usage

Comment: No, I put the lines in the models that were required in the instructions.

Comment: what about router.rb ?

Comment: I did literally everything that the instructions said to do line by line in each part of the app necessary.  That's why I'm so surprised that it does not work.  I can post other parts of my code if it'll help?

Comment: Try posting the full backtrace errors in your question. Not sure if that will help us but worth a shot.  You also may want to [open an issue](https://github.com/lml/commontator/issues/new) where the maintainers of the gem might be of more help.